# Opening a link in a new tab who's link values are stored in objects

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape this [Website](http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493). I have got the links of the companies in the site. I need to open each company in a new tab. All the links of companies are stored in the list `link`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")

#print link
for link in links:
    browser.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

So what i wanna do is open the link locations in links and open it in a new tab and perform some operation and close the tab and then open the next tab and so on for all the 365 pages.

Can somebody just point me to the right source or help me in enhancing the code to open a new tab with the link in the link list.

Answer (score 1):

You can ***navigate back*** to the previous page instead of opening pages on new window as it will increase handling issue.

But i will strongly recommend that ***Selenium WebDriver is not meant for scrapping purpose.***

There are alot of things, around, to do web scraping using Python.
**Here is a list of some useful links:**
***Scrapy Tutorial -*** http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html
***BeautifulSoup -*** http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/

I will recommend you to use *Scrapy*

Comment: I have never used scrappy/beautiful soap. What i'm trying to accomplish is that i need to open one of the links in the companies and then fetch company name, email, phone number and paste it into specific row/column in the excel sheet. Please recommend any tool which will do that..

Answer (score 0):

Selenium works badly with tabs. A better way is to use windows.

But the best way for scraping is:

1. To scrape the list of links from all needed pages;
2. in the loop use the same window/page to open links collected in first step.

Also, for security reasons, it would be better to set a delay between the scraping of the pages from links.

Also be attentive: Selenium is really slow for scraping large amounts of information. So it would be better to use an external scraper of html from text (html in this case will be received from Selenium). Example in C# -> `htmlAgrilityPack`. For python I have no idea. In this case the time of scraping can be 10,000 times faster!